# Online A/B test for recommendation system?

Tags: e-commerce, recommendation-engine, ab-testing

I was able to develop a couple of algorithms for my recommendation system, that I want to apply to an ecomm website.
My goal is to perform a live a/b test to check which system perform better. I would not rely only on offline metrics.
Does google optimize support this type of test? I have been investigating but I had no luck for now to find any documentation about it.
I would appreciate any additional insights or tips on how to apply the a/b test in this type of problem.
I have been doing all my development in Python.